# Makefile with different header directories?

Tags: c, makefile

```
//Root
Main.c
makefile
objs/  //I want to store the .o files here if possible.
refs/
    - header1.h
    - header1.c
    - up to 8 headers
```

So this is my file structure, I know it's not the best but it's just for a school project. The header files are included in the Main.c,

```
CC = gcc

INCLUDES = -I/refs

CFLAGS = -g $(INCLUDES)

ODIR = /objs

HLOC = /refs

main.o: main.c 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.c -o $(wildcard *.o)

main: main.o 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) main.c -o main

#clean:
    #rm $(wildcard *.o)
```

I am unsure how to actually do this, this is what I have so far but I unsure how to proceed or how to get this to work. I have searched extensively and cannot find an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: You may want to use `./refs` and `./objs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming "Main.c" at the top is a typo. I put this together without testing but it should at least convey the idea well enough. I used some GNU Automatic Variables in here, if you don't know about them [you should read the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html).
I made a target `default` which is going to build `objs` and then `bins`

```
# default target, will be called if no target provided
default: objs bins

CC = gcc
INCLUDES = -I./refs
CFLAGS = -g $(INCLUDES)
ODIR = ./objs
HLOC = ./refs

OBJS = $(ODIR)/main.o
BINS = main

# target called from default
objs: $(OBJS)

# target to build your object files
$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

#target for your binary
main: $(ODIR)/main.o 
    $(CC) $< -g -o $@

#clean build artifacts
clean:
    rm -f $(BINS)
    rm -f $(OBJS)
```

Don't forget that tabs are required on recipe lines. If you run into issues paste the errors you're getting!

Comment: oh my goodness thank you! I will keep looking over the manual  to check it out

Comment: @atltt73 No problem. The manual is definitely helpful, if you have time I'd read through the whole thing.